# How many ways to select 8 animals among goats, sheep, cows, horses and dogs?

Tags: combinatorics

The solution given considered it identical to finding the number of integral solutions to $$a+b+c+d=8$$

I know how to solve this. It's a straightforward stars and bars question. However, I approached the question in the following way - Each animal can be chosen in $4$ ways so the answer is $8^4$.

Although I understand the solution given, I don't understand these two approaches don't count the same entity. Can someone tell the mistake in my reasoning ?

Comment: Stars and bars is the correct way to do it.  What you have answered would be a slightly different question.  It would involve naming the animals.

Comment: 1. goats 2. sheep 3. cows 4. horses and **5**. dogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, there's 5 types of animals.  But let's pretend there's no dogs.

- $4^8$ counts length-8 sequences with elements chosen from {goat,sheep,cow,horse}.  So, e.g.,

  ```
  goat goat goat horse horse horse goat goat
  ```

  is one sequence and

  ```
  goat goat goat goat goat horse horse horse
  ```

  is another.  There are eight "slots", and for each slot, we can choose one of four animals.
- $8^4$ seems to be the above case with the numbers ($8$ and $4$) misplaced.

The first bullet point overcounts because we're counting selections of the same animals multiple times.

- The stars and bars method works fine, e.g. $$\star \star | \ | \star \star \star \star \star | \star$$ corresponds to "2 goats, 0 sheep; 5 cows; 1 horse", and we don't account for whether or not we choose goats before cows, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Counting 4 choices for each of the 8 slots double counts permutations. We don't care about the order in which the animals are chosen. So if you pick 3 goats, then 4 cows, and then another goat, that is the same as picking 4 goats and 4 cows. Your method, however, would count these as two distinct scenarios. Also, I believe you need five variables, since there are five types of animals according to the title.